# "unresolved variable js" in webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

in my "index.html" I wrote:

```
<script src = "scripts.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

(in my project there is file with this name: scripts.js)
but I get "unresolved variable js".
what can be the reason? thanks!

(also, I wrote:

```
<script src = "angular.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

and I get "cannot resolve file 'angular.min.js")

Comment: Are you using tags or just quotes?

Comment: tags, but SO delete what in tags, so i remove them

Answer (score 1):

All HTML `<script>` tags must have a separate closing tag: `</script>` or it will fail.

It is the one *weird* case in HTML where the tag won't have any content (when pulling in an external script) but can't be set as a "self-closing" tag.

Thus you want:

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry, i edited my post. In fact I did exactly what you wrote, just I got in trouble to copy into SO

Comment: is your code in the question correct now? or would you like help editing it to match what I wrote?

Comment: oh, sorry again... actually it's match to what you wrote. i hope now i typed it correct...

Comment: Is the `angular.min.js` file in the same directory as the code you've typed above? (PS we don't usually add spaces around the `=` character in HTML attributes, and the `type="text/javascript"` is redundant since it is the default type in HTML)

Comment: yes. it's in the same dir. scripts.js also. thanks on the tips :)

Comment: I saw when I run it - it's work fine (function of angular+function of scripts.js), so the problem is only in webstorm probably